# When does the overlying order matter?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn contains 5 red, 6 blue, and 8 green balls. If a set of 3 balls is randomly selected, what is the probability that each of the balls will be of the same color

I got 
$$
\frac {{3 \choose 1}{5 \choose 3} + {3 \choose 1}{6 \choose 3} + {3 \choose 1}{8 \choose 3}} {{19 \choose 3}}
$$

but the answer omits the ${3 \choose 1}$'s in the numerator. Can someone tell me why the colors are not taken into account when choosing for these balls?

Comment: If we are choosing a set of $3$ balls, the numerator should be $\binom{5}{3}+\binom{6}{3}+\binom{8}{3}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes but why wouldn't you add ${3 \choose 1}$ to ensure that they are of the same color? Because picking just any 5 balls, for example, wouldn't ensure they are all red.

Comment: The number of ways of choosing 3 red balls out of 5 total is $\binom{5}{3}$, the number of ways of choosing three 3 blue balls out of 6 total is $\binom{6}{3}$, and the number of ways of choosing 3 green balls out of 8 total is $\binom{8}{3}$. Adding these numbers counts the number of ways to pick three balls out of the urn, all the same color.

Comment: If you pick $3$ green they are automatically of the same colour. The same remark applies to the other colours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are finding the number of different ways this can occur. There are $5 \choose 3$ ways to choose 3 red balls and so on. You then divide by total possible options. The choosing colors would make sense if each of your ball amounts was the same. (e.g. 5 red, 5 blue, 5 green) Then $P=\dfrac{{3\choose 1} {5\choose 3}}{15\choose 3}$

Comment: So the ${3 \choose 1}$ pertains to choosing a group from 3 groups of 5 correct? And then the ${5 \choose 3}$ would then zone in on choosing 3 from that one group?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It's a matter of counting all the possibilities.

Comment: @shoestringfries In Konrad's formula, $\binom{3}{1}$ is choosing a color $C$ out of the three colors, and $\binom{5}{3}$ is choosing three balls out of the five total that have color $C$.